# expo: how can I download pdf with JWT token?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an app and I need to implement downloading invoices but with jwt token (the user has to authenticate before downloading the file) I looked up how to download pdf files but all the docs I found were without the auth so is there any way I can download file and send authentication header with request?

I found `expo-file-dl` but I don't know how to add an authentication header with URL

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetch` with required headers. Something like this could work:

```
fetch('url-to-file', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 
  }
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('...');
    }
    return response.blob();
  })
  .then((blob) => {
    // TODO e.g. save to file
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // TODO
  });
```